# How is New Soundcloud Top Bar Programmed?

Tags: jquery, uinavigationbar, soundcloud

I was curious to see if anyone knows how the new Soundcloud website was developed? Specifically, how does the song continue to play through the top bar audio player even after the user has navigated away from the song that is currently playing?

When you click on the top bar waveform, it then brings the user back to the active playing song. Could this same UX be replicated using AJAX and Jplayer?

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a blog post that goes into much detail about our front-end architecture – http://backstage.soundcloud.com/2012/06/building-the-next-soundcloud/

There is also a talk I gave on W3C Israel HTML5Fest http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXe9QjphsT8

Answering your question, yes, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to use jPlayer to do the same. At the moment our library of choice for playing audio is SoundManager though.

**UPD**. I'd definitely recommend looking into http://zohararad.github.com/audio5js/, it's a new library that let's you use HTML5 Audio with a Flash callback

Comment: Awesome this is really helpful!! We are thinking about using PJAX to reduce load time, but have pinterest style div containers that have the javascript library elements in each to play the music. Any recommendation to reduce load time/CPU load?

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me that SoundCloud is an SPA (single page application). Probably built using BackboneJS or some similar JavaScript lib...

SPA is concept of having only one page (in theory) that gets loaded synchronously. The rest is done by pulling views and other stuff from server via AJAX that are handled by some SPA library internally.

Regards.